# Reinstalling ruby

Tags: macos, ruby

I somehow screwed up my ruby installation. It says:

```
ruby ....
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1098:in `register_default_spec': undefined method `default_gems_use_full_paths?' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:699:in `block in load_defaults'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:647:in `block (2 levels) in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `block in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:653:in `each_default'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:698:in `load_defaults'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1239:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I updated all gems or something that like. How can I revert to the original ruby installation? I guess I have a timemachine backup, but maybe a clean reinstall is better.

**Edit:** OK, I deleted the gems as suggested in an answer, but when I try to reinstall them, I get:

```
gem install flickraw
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems /core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/util (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:527:in `gunzip'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:275:in `fetch_path'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:304:in `cache_update_path'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source.rb:130:in `load_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:230:in `tuples_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:199:in `block in available_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:55:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:55:in `each_source'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:195:in `available_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:81:in `search_for_dependency'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:139:in `spec_for_dependency'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:156:in `find_gems_with_sources'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:303:in `find_spec_by_name_and_version'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:109:in `available_set_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:329:in `install'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:166:in `block in execute'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `execute'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: OK, Edit was silly, I had to install as root. But after installing as root, the programms could not read the gem, so I had to change the permissions in /Library/Ruby/Gems/#num by hand. Now everything works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to clean up all of your Ruby gems with this Terminal command:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/#num
```

Where `#num` is your installed Ruby version (for Yosemite and Mavericks, [that should be 2.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#homebrew), and for Snow Leapard, Lion, and Mountain Lion, it should be 1.8).

It should also keep [all system-provided gems intact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227550/3366929), which is a good thing, because some applications may require them.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted them, but seem not to be able to add new ones.